# I make problem with embed posts on facebook from wp

Tags: wordpress, ssl, vps

Some days ago i change my hosting on vps and now when i embed posts on facebook i get this error cURL: SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Error on server - mod_fcgid: stderr: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/www/wp-content/themes/flex-mag/amp-single.php on line 29

PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/www/wp-content/themes/flex-mag/amp-single.php on line 29

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: file_get_contents(*/wp-content/themes/flex-mag/css/amp-media-queries.css): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/www-root/data/www/***/www/wp-content/themes/flex-mag/amp-single.php on line 29

OS VPS - CentOS 7

Please help me with this

Comment: What change did you made?

Comment: I did nothing, just download and upload sites on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your ssl-certificate expired or isnt valid anymore. You should check if http**s**://www.yoursite.any still works. If no, contact the hoster and ask him for a certificate (most do it)

Comment: https://newstime.in.ua Its work , i ask hoster about it and his cant help me with my server, -" because this is not a problem with the hosting "

Comment: Your website only outputs "Error establishing a database connection" so how should facebook be able to embed your posts?

Comment: Try it now, mby lagging , i can connect without problems on all my devices